# Why can't I list strings stored in arrays?

Tags: c

I started learning C recently. I'm having some difficulty with strings, especially in the matter of storing list of names, phrases, words and displaying them later. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char names[3][10];

    printf("Type 3 names: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        scanf("%10s", names);
    }

    printf("\n\nName list:\n\n");

    for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k<10; k++)
        {
        printf("%s", names[k][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My intention is to store full names and with spaces and display them listed later.

When I run the code, the program does not ask for 3 names and does not display correctly the ones that have been typed.

[image: error]

Any tips on how I can fix it?

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings to save you time.  `char names[3][10]; ...
        scanf("%10s", names);` should warn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please turn up the warning level of your compiler. It should have warned you about at least two things:

> (20): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int'
>
> (20): warning C4313: 'printf': '%s' in format string conflicts with argument 1 of type 'int'

In your first `for`-loop you do count to `3` but you miss specifying that you want to read from `stdin` to `names[i]`. Change

```
scanf("%10s", names);
```

to

```
scanf("%10s", names[i]);
```

In your second loop the nested `for`-loop is not neccessary since `printf()` will take care of printing each `char` in `names[j]` until it encounters a `'\0'` which terminates the string. So change

```
for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k<10; k++)
    {
    printf("%s", names[k][j]); // doesn't match. names[i][j] is a char *) 
    }
}
```

*) which propagates to an int due to parameter passing to a function with a variable length parameter list while the format string `"%s"` causes `printf()` to expect a pointer to `char`.

to

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    printf("%s\n", names[j]);
}
```

Please also mind that since you want to read names up to 10 characters in length your array needs to be

```
char names[3][11]; // not [3][10]
```

to accomodate for the terminating `'\0'` character.